# Stack Overflow on Lua metatable

Tags: lua

I used to have a construct that worked with luajit:

```lua
mytbl = setmetatable({1}, {__index = function(tbl,idx) return tbl[idx - 1] + 1 end})
```

Now with plain Lua 5.4 this gives me a stack overflow:

```
> mytbl[1000]
stdin:1: C stack overflow
stack traceback:
    stdin:1: in metamethod 'index'
    ....
```

The goal is to have a table where the default is to return the index itself:

```
mytbl[10]
```

should return 10. But when I say

```
mytbl[3] = 5
```

the value of

```
mytbl[10]
```

should be 12 (the values from 1 now yield 1,2,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,...)

Is there a way to get this in Lua 5.4 without the stack overflow? Or should I create another function for it?

Comment: Note that your current implementation has quadratic complexity when looping over items with e.g. `ipairs`.

Comment: @LMD Yes, thank you. I've tried to memoize values but this didn't solve the overflow. The approach Green posted is much better than my approach.

Comment: "But when I say `mytbl[3] = 5`" - will there be exactly one such assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with now:

```
__index=function(tbl, idx)
    local max = 0
    for k, v in next, tbl do
      if k <= idx then max = v - k end
    end
    return idx + max
  end
```

I only have very few entries in `tbl` so this should be reasonable fast for my purposes.

My test:

```
mytbl[5] = 9
for i = 1, 10 do
  print(mytbl[i])
end
```

outputs

```
1
2
3
4
9
10
11
12
13
14
```

Answer (score 3):

You are accessing the table within the `__index`. That causes another `__index` to be called and so on.

Use [`rawget`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-rawget) when you want to access the `tbl` itself.

If you want to get a custom logic that does not rely on existence of elements, write your function in a way that allows for trailing recursion or write it iteratively without any recursion at all:

```lua
__index=function(tbl, idx)
  local acc = 0
  for i=idx-1, 1, -1 do
    local th = rawget(tbl, i)
    if th then
      return acc + th + 1
    else
      acc = acc + 1
    end
  end
  return acc
end
```

Comment: Thank you, much better than my implementation!

Comment: @topskip, They both have the same problem of causing an explosion of complexity when used. I encourage you to write a trail recursive implementation for it. :) I fixed the early return just now, so it should be now passing your requirements.